# Entity Framework Json column mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Right, so I understand as of EF7 you can store Json data in columns without using value converters, but I can't quite figure out how it works. So I have the Table that goes into the DB:

```
public class ActivityLog 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; init; }
    public List<ActivityEntry> Log { get; set; } = new();
}
```

and

```
[NotMapped]
public class ActivityEntry
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

blah blah blah
}

So obviously each Log can have multiple entries. How do I set this up in the `OnModelCreating()` method?

Comment: Is ActivityEntry also a DbSet? Are you working with a Code or DB-First approach?

Comment: No, ActivityEntry isn't a dbset. The only way it should be persisted in the DB is serialised as json. And code first approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, EF cannot map the collection directly to JSON. It is necessary to introduce an intermediate type.

```
public class ActivityLog
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; init; }
    public LogMetadata LogMetadata { get; set; } = new();
}
public class LogMetadata
{
    public List<ActivityEntry> Log { get; set; } = new();
}
public class ActivityEntry
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ColumnValue { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

And configure it as follows.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ActivityLog>().OwnsOne(
        activityLog => activityLog.LogMetadata, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
        {
            ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
            ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsMany(metadata => metadata.Log);
        });
}
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Ah makes sense. I didn't realise I needed the intermediate class